# ListView as Grouped in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I am trying to implement **Expandable List View** in **Xamarin.Forms**, Since there is not inbuilt control, I am using simple List View and using it as Grouped. But I am not able find control of **Header Tap event**.

Is there such a tap event ?

Other possibilities of making Expandable List View in Forms ?

I have tried below code by using GestureRecognizer but tapping is not being captured.

lstView : List View with header as grouped.

```
Content = new StackLayout { 
                Children = {lstView}
            };
            var tap = new TapGestureRecognizer ();

            Content.GestureRecognizers.Add (tap);
            tap.Tapped += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
            {
                var x = e;
            };
```

Comment: Just read the site (first link I provided in my answer). You Need to create a custom control, which implements the GestureRecognizer (search for the ´StackLayoutButton´ on the said site

Answer (score 0):

The group-item has no built in Tap-event. The only way you can achive this, is by creating your own control for your group-template.

In this custom control you can add a GestureRecognizer for tap Events. You can also implement a property on which you can bind to (from your XAML). I can't give you a code-example, because I don't tried it yet (sorry for that).

But with the [infos here](http://blog.falafel.com/adding-tapped-event-gestures-xaml-control-xamarin-forms/), you should be able to do this.
I also found a [thread in the Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18725/expandable-listview-tableview-using-xamarin-forms), which describes the Problem you describe here (no soulition so far, but the infos maybe bring you to the right direction).

Comment: Yes, I have seen this link, but not able to implement.

Comment: Ok. Where's the Problem? Please update your question with your attempt on this, so maybe we can help you